# Display json local

Tags: css

I have been trying to display JSON data from one page to another on click.

For example, a user clicks on an image and it passes the same image/text to another page.

Here is my code

ygt.js

```
      <h2 class="pet-name">${pet.name}
      
      
      <h1 class="species">${pet.species}

      </div>
       <div></div></div>
      </div>
   </div>

  
`;
}

document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `
   <h1 class="app-title">Kids
   ${petsData.map(petTemplate).join("")}
`;
```

Comment: Why do all your header tag (`h1`, `h2`) not have close tag?

Comment: Does not matter it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use localStorage to pass the values from one page to another. Let's say you have the books in one page and you want to pass the book name to another page.

In your books page, you can add a function like this:

```js
function saveBook(bookName, link){
   localStorage.setItem("bookName", bookName):
   window.location.href = link
}
```

Then you can call this function in your `onclick` event.

```html
<div class="olay" onclick="saveBook('The Book','${pet.href}');" style="cursor: pointer;">
```

When someone clicks on the book, it will save the value in the localStorage and redirect to the page you need.

In the second page, you can use a function to retrieve the saved value:

```js
var bookName = localStorage.getItem('bookName');
```

More info on localStorage : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer I am not sure I understand will it be a bother if you create a fiddle? Also, I need it to display too

Comment: Still not working what could be wrong :/ https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-shape-816gn?file=/src/index.html

Comment: LocalStorage is disabled in most of the sandboxes. You have to use it locally.

Comment: @Luis Maximus You can use cookies as well.